# What does the definite integral of a space curve represent?

Tags: calculus, integration, curves

If I have a vector function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, I understand that I can use component-wise integration to recover a velocity function from an acceleration function, a position function from a velocity function, and so on.

Say now though that I have some vector function $\mathbf{r}$ that is unaffiliated with any sort of application.  Is there a geometric meaning of $\int\mathbf{r}$?

We know that $\mathbf{r}^\prime$ will tell us about the direction of a curve, and if $f$ is a scalar function, then $\int f$ tells us about the area under $f$, but what does $\int\mathbf{r}$ tell us?

Comment: You can think of the value of the line integral as the work done to follow the arc, working with/against the force field.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  In this case, the result of my definite integral will be a vector, because I am integrating component-wise.  Shouldn't work always be a scalar?  (Also, I'm not integrating in a vector field here. But maybe you're saying there's some interaction between a chosen vector field and the vector-valued result of my integration?)

Comment: Line integrals are written $\int\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$ for $\vec{F}$ a vector field and $r$ the curve we integrate over. By itself $\int\mathbf{r}$ has no meaning, because we need to integrate over a differential in multivariable calculus. If you mean $\int d\vec{r}$ instead, this is possible by simply setting $\vec{F}=\vec{1}.$

Comment: In particular, I mean something like $\int 5\mathbf{i}+t^3\mathbf{j}+(e^t-1)\mathbf{k}\,dt$, which Stewart's calculus text tells me is $5t\mathbf{i}+\frac{t^4}{4}\mathbf{j}+(e^t-t)\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{C}$.  (They also do examples where the integral is definite, which gives some vector as the result of the calculation.  In the indefinite case shown here, $C$ is a arbitrary constant vector.)